# Installing the Arduino Uno driver?

Tags: arduino, installation, driver, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

I recently bought an arduino uno and am following the instructions to install the drivers. The instructions say I need to find COM PORTS in DEVICE MANAGER in control panel but it's not there even when I choose display hidden objects in the device manager options.

I tried going into BIOS to enable PORTS but I can't seem to find an "advanced settings" or "peripherals" menu to do so. I have an Acer Aspire 5755G-6620 laptop.

Is there some way to enable PORTS or is there another way to install the driver?...

Thanks

Comment: I think you should post on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/. They also accept arduino questions. (and some of their moderators strongly opossed creation of independent arduino stack-exchange site)

Answer (score -1):

> If there is no COM & LPT section, look under "Other Devices" for "Unknown Device".

[Official Arduino Setup Guide](http://arduino.cc/en/guide/windows)

Comment: Hmmm there doesn't seem to be a "Other Devices" tab in device manager.